# Can I retake my instrument rating written and practical exam with the FAA?

Tags: instrument-rating

I was looking to get my restricted ATP at a university, but one of the requirements is to get my instrument rating from that university.  Since I already have my instrument rating, but have not flown for 20 years, I would like to get my rating again through the university. Is it possible to retake my instrument rating again with the FAA?  This would allow me to get my Restricted ATP with only 1,000 hours with 60 aviation credit hours from the university vs 1500 hours.

Comment: While I’m not familiar with the university or if this is really their requirement, you could always surrender your pilot certificate... I don’t think you can surrender just the instrument rating. That would mean you would need to do your private checkride and written again. The thought of surrendering any of my hard earned certificates makes me cringe!

Comment: I would check more thoroughly if this is what they really require or if there is some other way to validate your IR through them, such as an IPC, or merely graduating from their IR program, even though you have already your rating.

Comment: This seems like a University specific policy question.

Answer (score -5):

You don't still have an instrument rating if you've not flown in 20yrs. It is long expired and basically doesn't exist. Its best to do a refresher with CFII and take IPC eval when ready. Or you could redo the whole IR, and or re take the written. I belive the most current written is the one prominent in your file so yeah, go for a better score.

Comment: Currency expires, the rating does not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).